# Count how many hours are in specific year

Tags: r

I want to have number, which shows how many hours are in a specific year. Is there any function?

Comment: That's a simple question to ask, but not an easy one to answer.  Do you mean complete hours?  (Leap seconds)  Are you prepared for geographic differences (1940 in GB: double summer time: the clocks went forward in the spring, but did not go back in the autumn/fall, so 1940 was an hour shorter than you might expect). And what about the adoption of the Gregorian calendar throughout much of Europe in 1582? The 4th of October was followed immediately by the 15th of October.  Etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Something likes this?

```
library(lubridate)

get_hours <- function(date)
  if(leap_year(as.Date(date)){
    366*24
  } else {
    365*24
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot the ```return```, youre right.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(lubridate)

hoursOfYear <- function(year) {
  x <- ymd_hms(paste0(year, '01', '01','00:00:00'))
  y <- ymd_hms(paste0(year, '12', '31','24:00:00'))
  return (interval(x,y) %/% hours(1))
}

hoursOfYear('2020')

#> [1] 8784
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an hourly sequence and count its length, i .e.

```
length(seq(as.POSIXct('2019-01-01 00:00'), as.POSIXct('2020-01-01 00:00'), by = 'hour'))
#[1] 8761
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difftime` specifying `units` as "hours".

```
number_of_hours_in_year <- function(year) {

     as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(paste0(year+1, '-01-01')), 
                         as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01')), units = "hours"))
}

number_of_hours_in_year(2018)
#[1] 8760

number_of_hours_in_year(2020)
#[1] 8784
```